# Are "spite renewals" (like on Episodes) a real thing?

Tags: episodes-2011

The TV series Episodes depicts a satirized version of the TV industry. On the show, Matt LeBlanc stars on (Lousy Show) on (Network 1), which everyone knows is about to be canceled - in fact, Matt is already developing (New Project) for (Network 2).

When (Network 1) finds out about (New Project), it renews (Lousy Show) for another season for the sole purpose of blocking Matt from working for (Network 2).

Do US TV networks really do things like that?

Comment: Given the massive drop in quality some shows experience after their first season, I’d say it’s plausible.